# Setting up URL Rewrite rule for a specific domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-8

For local dev testing, I need to catch all requests to `www.somedomain.com/XXX` (where X is the path), and send them on to `localhost/somevdir/XXX`.

I've added this to my HOSTS file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc):

```
127.0.0.1   www.mydomain.com
```

Then, in IIS8 (Windows 8), I've added a binding to my "Default Web Site" for the host www.mydomain.com. This works, I can now browse www.mydomain.com/test.html and see a test html page. My virtual dir is inside the Default web site. I then add a URL Rewrite URL to the web site for the last bit:

```xml
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^www.mydomain.com/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="localhost/MyVDir/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But - that doesn't work. I get a 404 so it looks the the match never happens. I've tried redirect and rewrite, and I've tried without the ^ in the regex and a few other regex tweaks. Can someone explain what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```xml
<rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(mydomain\.com|www\.mydomain\.com)$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/MyVDir/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

The match on any URL makes sure the conditions are checked, and the HTTP_HOST server variable seems the most reliable way of checking the requested hostname. You could remove the REQUEST_FILENAME input condition, but it works as quite a nice sanity check to make sure static files are always served.

Comment: Almost :) I had to use a redirect (rewrite didn't work), and had to specify the full path with the host (`http://localhost/MyVDir/{R:1}`) but once I'd done that, I was in :)

Comment: Shouldn't you be escaping the periods in the pattern for your domain names?  ^((mydomain\.com)|(www\.mydomain\.com))$

Comment: Good spot, luckily the any character matching from periods is unlikely to be a problem as most people won't have wwwXmydomain.com where X is a random letter. The extra parenthesis aren't needed.

Comment: this also helps a lot with subdomain situations like, the main domain is gonna redirect all HTTP to HTTPS, but I don't want that to happen with my subdomain like 'app2.mydomain.com' should still respond on HTTP as well... this helps a lot by excluding the subdomain from the rule. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The following is better for catching both `www.` and non-`www.` versions of the domain so that you don't have to write the domain twice, which could possibly cause errors with being twice as likely to write a typo. (The parenthesis with the `?` character means optional in regex terms.)

```
<rule name="mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?mydomain\.com$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/MyVDir/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```